# How can I mimic C++ style overloading in this PHP code

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism, overloading

I have a static function in PHP:

```
public static function func( $foo, $bar ) {

}
```

where `$bar` is an integer.  I want to implement a similar `func` but where `$bar` is a string.  In C++ I would use overloading but the PHP documentation shows that overloading doesn't do the same as C++.  Is there some other way I can achieve what I want?

One alterative that I thought about is some polymorphism but it seems kind of overkill?:

Make an interface with `func` defined (with no implementation) and just implement it in two different ways.  So:

```
interface Something {
   public static function func( $foo, $bar );
}

class Something1 implements Something {
   public static function func( $foo, $bar ) {
      // some implementation
   }
}

class Something2 implements Something {
   public static function func( $foo, $bar ) {
      // some other implementation
   }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: PHP does type convertion for you, if you want you can typecast some like return parent::func($foo, string $bar)

Also in weakly typed languages types are implicitly polymorphic.

Comment: PHP has no function signature based overloading. Get used to it. Also please do some search before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+method+overloading

Answer (score 2):

Overloading in the sense of C++ or any other static typed language does not make sense
in php, because you not need to make a type hint. That´s the nature of weakly typed languages
and so it would not be a benefit in having this feature in php. You can pass any variable of any type to your function. In the case of objects you have polymorphism without having to use inheritance/interfaces to achieve polymoprhic behaviour. That´s called duck typing.

If you need different implementation for string/int, just check the type and provide the implementation in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Create one function, and depending on the type of that parameter, do different things or call the actual functions, func_int and funct_string. You're effectively doing the dispatch yourself.

For checking the type, there are [gettype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), and the `is_..` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help, you identify what type is $bar and then call the corresponding function.

```
public static function func( $foo, $bar ) {
   if (is_int($bar)) {
       self::funcBarInteger($foo, $bar);
   } else {
       self::funcBarString($foo, $bar);
   }
}

public static function funcBarInteger( $foo, $bar ) {

}

public static function funcBarString( $foo, $bar ) {

}
```

Comment: That's fine but not as slick being able to overload like in C++.